# how to replace values of selected row of a column in panda's dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, anaconda

i have train dataset which has 12 columns. 
[image]

I want to select **Cabin** column rows according to **Pclass** column's value 1. 
And then replace value of selected rows of Cabin column with 1.

i did following code but it replace all values of cabin column with 1 even NaN values replace by 1.How i can replace only selected rows?

```
train['Cabin'] =train[train['Pclass']==1]['Cabin']=1
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can select by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with condition rows of column `Cabin` and set to scalar:

```
train.loc[train['Pclass'] == 1, 'Cabin'] = 1
```

And your code replace all values to `1` because is is same as:

```
train['Cabin'] = 1
```

**Sample**:

```
train = pd.DataFrame({'Pclass':[1,2,3,1,2],
                      'Cabin':[10,20,30,40,50]})
print (train)
   Cabin  Pclass
0     10       1
1     20       2
2     30       3
3     40       1
4     50       2

train.loc[train['Pclass'] == 1, 'Cabin'] = 1
print (train)
   Cabin  Pclass
0      1       1
1     20       2
2     30       3
3      1       1
4     50       2
```

Comment: What if the value you want to assign (1 in this example) is not a constant?  I have a case which, using the variables here, could translate to something like `if Pclass < 3, then Cabin = 2*Pclass`.  I tried ```train.loc[train['Pclass'] < 3, 'Cabin'] = train.loc[train['Pclass'] < 3, 'Pclass']*2```, but I get neither result nor error...

Comment: @AstroFloyd - code seems fine, should working well.

Comment: @AstroFloyd - Testing and working well for me.

Comment: Perhaps I made a mistake in the translation from my situation to your example.  I found a solution using the [pandas.DataFrame.where()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) method.

Answer (score 0):

you can directly filter the rows you want to change and assign the value to it instead of filtering, replacing and then assigning to the dataframe.

So

```
train['Cabin'] =train[train['Pclass']==1]['Cabin']=1
```

becomes

```
train['Cabin'][train['Pclass']==1] = 1
```